# Convert this SQL to LINQ

Tags: sql, linq

How do I do this query in linq? All the tables already are list of objects.

This query give points to entities named "Empresas" (Companies) that fills the "Palavras" (Words) criterias.

```
select x.empresaid, sum(x.pontos)

from (

        select a.empresaid, sum(1) as Pontos
        from empresa  a
        inner join Palavras b on a.nome like '%' + b.Palavra + '%'
        group by a.empresaid

        union all

        select a.empresaid, sum(case when c.estabelecimento is null then 0 else 1 end) as Pontos
        from empresa  a
        left join estabelecimentoempresa b on b.empresaid = a.empresaid
        left join estabelecimento c on c.estabelecimentoid = b.estabelecimentoid
        left join Palavras d on c.estabelecimento like '%' + d.Palavra + '%'
        group by a.empresaid

        union all

        select a.empresaid, sum(case when c.Cozinha is null then 0 else 1 end) as Pontos
        from empresa  a
        left join Cozinhaempresa b on b.empresaid = a.empresaid
        left join Cozinha c on c.Cozinhaid = b.Cozinhaid
        left join Palavras d on c.Cozinha like '%' + d.Palavra + '%'
        group by a.empresaid
    ) x

group by x.empresaid

order by sum(x.pontos) desc, x.empresaid
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you would be able convert as it is from SQL to LINQ.  You could still try this tool that convert SQL to LINQ syntax:

http://www.sqltolinq.com/

The preferable approach is to understand and write the LINQ syntax on your own.